# How to convert MM/dd/yyyy to yyyy/MM/dd in C# using globalization

Tags: c#, globalization

I have a text box in which a user is supposed to enter a date in MM/dd/yyyy format. This date is stored as yyyy/MM/dd in the database.

I want the user to enter the date in MM/dd/yyyy format and later I want to convert it to yyyy/mm/dd so that I can query the database.

How can I convert the user input date MM/dd/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd?

Comment: why the hell are you storing a date in the database as a STRING?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're certain of the input string's format, use DateTime.ParseExact specifying "MM/dd/yyyy", then return the DateTime using .ToString with the appropriate "yyyy/MM/dd" format string.

There's no need to reference anything in the System.Globalization namespace for this.

That said, your database should be storing dates with a datetime format, rather than a string, in which case the format doesn't matter as your DBMS should do the conversion for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the date and format the result:

```
string str = Date.Parse(myDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Alternatively, if the current culture doesn't support that date format and you've already validated the input:

```
string items[] = myDate.Split('/');
string str = items[2] + "/" + items[0] + "/" + items[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you said globalization, I assume you want the change to be automatic according to current culture

You can setup culture (at Global.asax.cs I suggest)

```
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("the culture you want to set"); //
```

you do not need to touch any datetime thing, it just happened when you output them.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is not the other.

Not sure why you want to insist on the text entered being MM/dd/yyyy, or why you haven't used a date time picker to make sure it is a date.

But at the point you get the content of the textbox as a date, parse it based on globalisation, or a set of acceptable formats. Now it is a date, and assuming it's a date in the database, format is irrelevant until you come to populate the text box, with some content from the DB, inwhich case you use DateTime's ToString method witha globalisation parameter, usually CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, or if you've got away with it CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.
If it's a string in the DB, then this is the least of your problems.

They key point is if you use dates properly, format is only relevant for Parse, and ToString type methods.

Answer (score 0):

i am using

```
IFormatProvider culture=new CultureInfo("en-GB",true);
sqlcommand cmd=new sqlcommand("query",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",DateTime.Parse(txtdate.Text.Trim(),culture,DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault).Date);
```

for this to work the format property must be set to dd/MM/yyyy
and text box read only property must be false